# Javascript How can i make the 'else' output something only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I've been experimenting with for loop with 2-dimensional array, obviously i am new to javascript and programming in general.. I am trying to find a var inside the array if found then output success message and if not output a failed message. Whenever i make the code output the failed message it appears on the console 4 times and the success message still shows..

Expected output if fail:

```
No matching keyword was found
```

Result output:

```
The keyword String is found 
No matching keyword was found 
No matching keyword was found 
No matching keyword was found 
No matching keyword was found
```

---

```
newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35]];


var find = "String";
for(var i=0; i< newArray.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j < newArray.length + i; j++){
        if (newArray[i][j] === find){
            console.log("The keyword " + find + " is found");
        } else {
            console.log("No matching keyword was found");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: method 1: use a variable to indicate it's been output before, and don't output. method 2: rethink your code, as it stands it doesn't really make much sense

Comment: I think your `loop` is good. It does go through all your data. You have 5 items so for sure it will do a compare 5 times also. Given than you log on each compare you get 5 logs in total. 1 found and the rest is not found.

Comment: @Jalil thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what they said, use a variable as an indicator.

```
newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35]];


var find = "String";
var found = false;
for(var i=0; i< newArray.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j < newArray[i].length + i; j++){
        if (newArray[i][j] === find){
            console.log("The keyword " + find + " is found");
            found = true;
        }
    }

}
if (!found) {
    console.log("No matching keyword was found");
}
```

Please analyze and compare our code to prevent you from asking similar question in the future.

Now, try to optimize above by not iterating over the other elements after we "found" it's match.

Comment: Thanks, i should have think harder

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is incorrect.

In your inner loop, you have to loop on `newArray[i]`
Also, when search is is a success, use `break`.

Also use a variable to indicate that operation has come to an end.

```
 newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35]];

 var find = "String";

  var end = false;
   for(var i=0; i< newArray.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j < newArray[i].length; j++){
               if (newArray[i][j] === find){
                    console.log("The keyword " + find + " is found");
                     end = true;
                     break;
                } else {
                     console.log("No matching keyword was found");
                 }
          }
           if (end) {
                 break;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35]];


var find = "String";
for(var i=0; i< newArray.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j < newArray[i].length + i; j++){// <--- you want to iterate only as many times as the inner array elements. Right now you iterate over the same array index as the first loop.
        if (newArray[i][j] === find){
            alert("The keyword " + find + " is found");
            return; //<-- end script after result is found
        } 
    }
}
//Will only get here if the return was not hit
alert("No matching keyword was found");
```

You are seeing it 4 times because the loop will keep running until it has iterated over everything. One way to to do what you want is is to end the script after the result is found.

If you want to take the slick es6 approach :

```js
newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35,"String"]];
const term = "String2";
const isFound = newArray.some(e=>e.find(e=>e===term));
alert(`The keyword has ${isFound ? "" : "not"} been found`);
```

Answer (score -1):

use a boolean to store a flag "isFound", and break on found.

```
newArray = [["String","Sa"],[1,2,35]];
var find = "String";
var isFound = false;
for(var i=0; i< newArray.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j < newArray.length + i; j++){
        if (newArray[i][j] === find){
            console.log("The keyword " + find + " is found");
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (isFound == false){
console.log("No matching keyword was found");
}
```